# Query References Another - Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba, pass-through

Good morning,

I just received a new assignment and I am struggling with finding an appropriate solution. I have searched through the SO Forums, and through Google, but have not found a workable solution.  Below is my scenario:

We are working out of Microsoft Access to connect to an SQL Server Database via an ODBC Connection.

I wasgiven an incredibly large pass-through SQL query, larger than is able to be processed in MS Access. In this pass-through query, there is a subquery in a WITH...AS method.

I am hoping to be able to split this one, singularly large, SQL pass through query into two: Query One (the subquery), and Query Two (which references the results of the subquery)

I know that by using general Access queries, I can write a Macro like follows...

```
Sub myQuery()
' Edited from http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1667831-Run-multiple-queries-in-sequence-on-click

' On Error GoTo ErrHandler

' Run the first query
MsgBox "Starting first query"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "first_Query"
DoEvents

' Run the second query
MsgBox "Done. Now starting second query"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "second_Query"
DoEvents

MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

However, these need to be pass-through queries. I believe that the enormously large SQL String is created via a number of user inputs. Regardless, I don't have the ability to change the pass-through SQL that I was given.

Is there anyway I can write a macro that calls the first pass-through query, and then calls the second pass-through query that REFERENCES the result of the first?

Here is an example with what I am working with...

```
WITH queryOne AS
    (
        SELECT fooID
        FROM tblFoo
        WHERE foodate > ...
    )

SELECT foo, fooone, footwo, foothree
FROM tblOtherFoo
WHERE fooID = OtherFooID
```

However, the query is 50000+ characters, exceeding that ~37k limit.

Please feel free to ask any questions. I am stumped by this and would appreciate any feedback or alternative resources.

Thank you!

Comment: A query that is 9,000 lines long is a nightmare and a very clear sign that something has gone very horribly wrong. I would for starters create a stored procedure instead of doing this in Access. If you build your queries in Access the front and back end are tightly coupled which is not a good practice. But seriously.....9,000 lines in a single query?

Comment: This just sounds awful all around. 9000 line query?? REALLY. That seems way out of control.

Comment: @SeanLange

I didn't write it, it's basically selecting a bunch of individual Purchase Orders out of this huge purchase order table we have. So the subquery grabs the PO ID's, and the second grabs the other information that's needed for our analysis. But, it's only certain Purchase Orders, and the overall string exceeds too many characters.

Again, I didn't write it, unfortunately I'm just stuck trying to get it to work. So I'm sure you understand my trouble.

Comment: I have tried changing the SQL a little bit to using aliases and whatnot to lessen the requirement, but it still greatly exceeds the ~37k or so limit that MS Office products have.

Comment: I understand you didn't write it, but that doesn't make it less horrific. Seriously...9,000 lines is not a query. That is more code than most dotnet classes have even with embedded sql. Assuming you can fit 100 lines on a page this query would be 90 pages. That is not a query, it is the first third of a novel. This needs to be completely rethought and rewritten. I am actually sugar coating just how absolutely awful this is.

Comment: @SeanLange please keep in mind that each "OR" statement is on it's own line.

PO_ID = 'XXXX'
OR
PO_ID = 'XXXX'
OR etc....

I appreciate your concern, but all I am looking to do is find a way to have one PTQ reference the results of a previously called one.

Comment: OK. If you have that type of thing spanning hundreds and hundreds of lines then something is still horribly wrong. It sounds like it was created by somebody who didn't really understand databases and has now handed that off to you and you are left to pick up the pieces. I feel for you, but it really does need an overhaul and rebuild.

Comment: @SeanLange probably correct. Even each SELECT item is on a different line, as is each OR, each AND, etc.

Comment: OK. But 50,000+ characters is not manageable. I don't care if that is one line or 100,000 that is not a query that is put together correctly. My guess is you have all kinds of hard coded values in there. That sort of thing would be better suited with another table and some joins. I don't normally say this but I think you need to hire a consultant to come on site and help you guys unravel this. \

Comment: @SeanLange I appreciate your input, and I think a redesign effort should definitely be considered. However, like I've mentioned, I am seeking for help with designing a Macro or a way where one PTQ can reference another. I think that is accomplish-able on this site, given the genius and communal aspect to most of the members here. If you are unable to help, while I appreciate your input, I will leave this open to see if anybody else is able to help me find a way to allow one PTQ to reference another.

Comment: The only way you would be able to do something like that would be to use the first query to pull everything back. And then do a loop across that entire set and find only the data you want. No matter how you slice this the performance is going to be really bad. And sadly you are doing it right now instead of doing it right. But I leave that decision to you. As for a real answer here it is nearly impossible because can't see your query or the tables involved.

Answer (score 0):

It not clear what you mean by something that references the first or previous? Why break up something you been given that supposed works just fine?

So just place that existing t-sql you been given into a stored procedure. In T-SQL you can easy have some SQL operate on some previous SQL, but why break up such a HUGE massive monster slew of code and introduce bugs? It will take you YEARS AND YEARS to break up a KNOWN working huge T-SQL that been built and developed for you (something that long likely took a few years and a team of developers to create).

A conservative estimate would be such a routine cost $50,000, or even $100,000 to develop.

No question that the working T-SQL you been given might reference previous data, or even do selects into #Temp tables that additional T-SQL can work on.

If you ALREADY have a working PT code and query given to you?

Simply take that T-SQL query, and simply paste it into a stored procedure. You will do this in SQL Server and NOT even touch or bother with Access.

So don't create some macro in Access that calls multiple separate queries, but place all of the T-SQL in a stored procedure, and simply call that huge mess one time from Access.

It possible that the T-SQL you been given is incorrect, but assuming that the T-SQL is correct, then simply place all that long mess into a working stored procedure. You do not place this SQL in MS Access and you don’t need to have that mess inside of Access.

So get that T-SQL working in SQL Server – don’t bother with MS Access until this long query mess is working in SQL Server. ONLY THEN do you fire up Access.

So you THEN create a simple PT query in Access that calls the huge long T-SQL mess you been given. But that “mess” is to be placed in SQL Server – not in Access.

So create a PT query in Access that calls your “supposed” working T-SQL you been given. The SQL you save in the Access PT query will be this

```
Exec my_StupidLongSQLProc
```

Save the above as a PT query. Then in VBA code go:

```
Currentdb.QueryDefs("MyPTQuery").Execute
```

If you need to pass some values from Access, then go:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPTQuery")
   .sql = "exec My_StupidLongSQLproc " & p1 & "," p2
   .Execute
End with
```

In above we pass two VBA values from Access to the big mess of sql you have – the stored procedure in above is just an example that access two parameters passed from Access VBA. If the T-SQL you been given does not require values from Access, then the first single .execute will do the job.

And if you REALLY did get such a long routine that is correct T-SQL, then it likely already has parameters in the working T-SQL (and again you don’t want to mess with or change such a huge long working T-SQL that you been given).

So you only need one line of code in Access, and your existing long T-SQL you been given if written correctly can be placed in a stored procedure (assuming that you actually been given a correctly working PT query).

So if you REALLY did get a huge massive working T-SQL statement, then simply place that KNOWN AND WORKING T-SQL in SQL Server as a stored procedure and call it with one line of code as per above.

So trying to split this up from Access will only server to cause world-wide poverty and ANY tiny miss step or breaking up of that huge long routine will cause world-wide poverty and starving children as you try and “fix” this great working T-SQL that you been given. As noted, something that long to create would take a teams of developers HUGE resources. If you touch or break up one line of code and mess it up, then you need that team of developers to spend several months trying to fix what you broke.

So the INSTANT you start breaking up such a huge long mess is the instant you lost this battle and will waste several years of your life trying to fix this crazy long T-SQL that you been given that is already claimed to be proper working code.

Comment: I never once said I was using T-SQL, and I'm not, so therefore I can't do stored procedures.

It is literally a really large query that has 3 basic parts: SELECT, FROM,  WHERE. The WHERE clause has thousands of WHERE PO_ID = 'xxxx' OR PO_ID = 'xxxx'

I never once mentioned I was using T-SQL, I also cannot do stored procedures being that I'm not an admin.

Though I appreciate you taking the time to write out such a long answer, it was rude and unhelpful. thanks.

Comment: You should also see where I said I can't paste in the SQL I was given because it exceeds the character limit in Access...which is why I'm here...

Comment: Well, if you talking about a PT query, then it MUST be T-SQL, and it cannot work any other way. A PT query ONLY works with T-SQL. So if you not going to use t-sql, then how on earth can you use and be talking about a PT query then??? Again: A PT query MUST be t-sql and  PT query ONLY works with t-sql. And you don't necessary have to use a store proc. If in fact this is t-sql (and it has to be for a PT query), then create a sql view). If that sql is not t-sql then it can't be used for a PT query and you have to stop talking about a PT query then, right????

Comment: Not quite...you can simply use the MS Access interface to "write" your query, click the pass-through button and it becomes a pass-through query...you can also write it using pass-through syntax without it being in t-sql...

Comment: No, if you change a query to pass-though, then the sql must ALSO be changed to T-SQL. Again: If you taking about a PT query, then the sql in that query MUST be T-SQL. You MUST use 100% SQL server sql (that means t-sql). So anyone talking and posting about a PT query by logic MUST BE talking about T-SQL. One more time: Any sql in a PT query must be of the t-sql syntax else it will not work.

Comment: I will also add that that  you can write some queries in the access query builder, and such sql will work both as Access SQL, and T-SQL since they are rather similar. However, when you change the query to PT, Access does NOT automatic re-write or modify the syntax to work as t-sql. At the end of the day, if you use a PT query, then the SQL in that query MUST BE of correct t-sql syntax. So sure in some cases a Access query will work as t-sql since the syntax is often very close. However, if the query is not 100% t-sql compatible, then it will not work and will NEVER work.